# What should I name a program in a web page?

Tags: terminology

I am designing a new programming language that will be nested in a web page. Is it a good idea to name your programming language something generic, like "Program Designer" or "Program Maker", or something like "Jet" or "Hawk"? (Just ideas)

Which would attract more users? A descriptive, somewhat boring name, or a un-descriptive, but cool, name?

Comment: If the question is purely about naming a product, this is more marketing related than UX. Even then, it'd be about doing market research for your specific target demographic and not something we could easily answer here.

Comment: That said, naming a product with a generic name is rarely a winning marketing move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this exactly fits UX, but it seems like the naming convention for programming languages is to name it something interesting and catchy if its the first of its lineage, or base the name of its predecessors if it its a derivative of another language.

> ## Python
>
> When it came time to pick a name for his creation, van Rossum wanted something "short, unique and slightly mysterious." He found his inspiration in the famous British comedy group Monty Python, of which he was a big fan. No word on whether he considered Parrot for the name.
>
> ## Java
>
> was originally called Oak, but once Sun's lawyers determined that that name was already trademarked, they had to pick a new one.
>
> ## Groovy
>
> His solution? Design a new language that would dynamically compile into Java bytecode and that, in his own words, "builds right on top of all the groovy Java code out there."

http://www.itworld.com/article/2823913/enterprise-software/145128-A-method-to-the-madness-How-13-programming-languages-got-their-names.html

> ## Javascript
>
> Because Java was a competitor of C++ and aimed at professional programmers, Netscape also wanted a lightweight interpreted language that would complement Java by appealing to nonprofessional programmers

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript

But in the end, the functionality behind your language is going to be the determining factor. If it works well people will use it no matter the name.

EDIT: It should be noted I don't actually know the history of programming languages, I don't know what languages were based on what it is just my observations.

Comment: I think many would argue JavaScript was one of the more poorly named programming languages ever. :)

Answer (score 2):

Both. You don't want to be generic and use exclusively 'related' terms, but you don't want to have any unrelated stuff (airplane photos etc) coming up.

For example, HawkScript.

Then if the name becomes popular enough people will just start calling it 'hawk' for short.

Personally, I think hawk is still a pretty common term though. How about something more unique like a vanga (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmet_vanga) or a turaco(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turaco)?